# Не подключается socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Со стороны клиента не работает socket.io, когда подключаю вот так `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, то файл не находит, если так `<scriptsrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"</script>`, то в консоль постоянно выкидываются ошибки типа `GET https://php-justrelaxdc.c9users.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LzihL5H 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Зачем? Когда везде в нормальных браузерах давно есть `WebSocket`

Comment: Поподробнее можно?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets - куда еще подробнее?

Comment: А как вы его подключаете-то? Со стороны сервера?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает чат Node.js + apache(php)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737583/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-node-js-apachephp)

Answer (score 0):

а ты устанавливал для этого файлы? Если нет, то вот на онлайн редакторе ты можешь просто запустить свой node.js(index.js) и программа сама установит нужные файлы, а если ты работаешь не на онлайн редакторе, то вот так нужно установить файлы перед написанием кода в index.js:
Просто зайди на официальный сайт и скачай: [сайт для скачивания](https://nodejs.org)

Либо введи в консоль:
`npm install socket.io`